# Raspberry Pi to tor my network of further device connected?

Tags: raspberry-pi, router, tor, anonymous

How to do it can anyone help?
I want to achieve a connection on my end device that goes through tor and for that raspberry pi is used.
The network structure is as follows,

1. ISP router
2. LAN connection to Raspberry Pi
3. Raspberry Pi making my traffic connection through tor
4. Now a USB to LAN cable goes to my Internal Access Point(USB port of Raspberry Pi sending further internet traffic data over tor to my Internal AP)
5. Now all my End Devices connected to that Internal AP making all the devices anonymous and traffic is going through tor network.

[BluePrint of Netwwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4hEE.jpg)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to achieve above? Telling everyone what you've done? What is the current blocker?

Comment: How to achieve it

Comment: current blocker is that everyone is using inbuilt wifi of pie but I want to use another router.